# Compress images with PHP

Tags: php, image, image-processing, compression

I process uploaded images by php to save (after resize) by `imagejpeg`. As I explored, `imagejpeg` is the best php command to compress jpg images to reduce the file size. However, when I check my website by Google Page Speed, it says all of my images can be compressed 4-10%.

What is the common method to compress images to meet the Google standard?

Comment: Can you add a URL so we can have a look?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Googles "standard" is the possible maximum to be expected by google. You need to use highly optimized image compressors that does nothing else than image compressing and therefore get a possible maximum best value here.

You can for example, open you jpeg file in a image editor like adobe photoshop and create the possible maximum best compression to be expected by you while having visual control. Highly recommended.

The GD library provides a standard conform jpeg compression which should match a library users expectation, but which might not satisfy a graphic designer (and/or google by 4-10%).

Comment: Since users upload the images on the website, it is not convenient to process it with a software like photoshop. I am looking for a script to do so. There are online services to compress images; thus, it should be possible to make further compression through common scripts. Maybe not GD but ImageMagick ...

Comment: There are even libraries that are specialized for automatic jpeg image compression. Look for those.